# function pointer in C strange behaviour

Tags: c, pointers, function-pointers

I have a small program that uses function pointers.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct _myst
{
    int a;
    char b[10];
}myst;

void cbfunc(myst *mt)
{
    fprintf(stdout,"called %d %s. \n",mt->a,mt->b);
}

int main()
{

    /* func pointer */
    void (*callback)(void *);

    myst m;
    m.a=10;
    strcpy(m.b,"123");

    /* point to callback function */
    callback = (void*)cbfunc;

    /* perform callback and pass in the param */
    callback(&m);

    return 0;

}
```

The function pointer decleration

```
void (*callback)(void*);
```

declares a function pointer `callback` that takes a generic-pointer and returns void.

While assigning `cbfunc` to `callback`

```
callback = cbfunc;
```

I get the warning

```
warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
```

If I use the following

```
callback = (void*)cbfunc;
```

It compiles without any warnings.I am using gcc (4.6.3) and compiling with CFLAGS=-g -O3 -Wall

Can someone explain the reason for this?

Comment: The reason for what? For the warning or the lack thereof (when you cast)?

Comment: @H2C03 - yes for lack of warning when you cast.

Comment: The parameter types in the function pointer declaration need to match the parameter types in the actual function.

Comment: @liv2hak The reason for that is that your compiler is overly permissive and enables you to assign a pointer-to-`void` to a variable of type pointer-to-function. It's in fact wrong, and should not be allowed, because the two types are not compatible, but most compilers enable it by default anyway.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Why does the assignment generate a warning?

You have a super power: you can make friends with any dog.  You are put into a box that says "the person in this box can make friends with any animal". Then someone puts a tiger in your box. How's your day going now?

Now do you see why the assignment is a warning? You have a method that states it can accept any pointer to `myst` and you are putting it in a box that says "the function pointed to by this pointer can accept a pointer to anything".  That's potentially dangerous; what's stopping the user of that function pointer from passing a pointer to a tiger into the function?

> Why does the compiler suppress the warning when there is a cast?

**Because that's the purpose of a cast**. A cast operator means "compiler, I know the thing I am doing is crazy dangerous but I mean to do it and know it will work, so stop giving me warnings and errors about this crazy conversion". Casts effectively turn off the safety system. **If that's not what you mean to do then don't write a cast**.

Answer (score 8):

Change `void (*callback)(void *);` to `void (*callback)(myst *);`, since this is what your function actually is.

Comment: what does the cast mean?

Comment: You would call it like this: `callback((void *)&m);`, casting `&m` to a `void *`.

Comment: But if he casts `m` when he calls the function through the function pointer it won't get rid of the warning when assigning the function to the function pointer.

Comment: @nonsensickle Point (I think i'm half asleep). I'll remove that part from the answer.